# Non Redundant Image Extraction From Video

Tags: artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, data-collection

I am collecting data for a project. The data collection is done by recording videos of the subjects and the environment. However, while training the network, I would not want to train it with all the images collected in the video sequence.

The main objective is to not train the network with redundant images. The video sequence collected at 30 frames/sec can have redundant images (images that  are very similar) within the short intervals. T(th) frame and (T+1)th frame can be similar.

Can someone suggest ways to extract only the images that can be useful for training ?

Comment: you should follow this to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Update #2:** Further resources,

https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/27/image-hashing-opencv-python/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/04/20/detect-and-remove-duplicate-images-from-a-dataset-for-deep-learning/

**Update #1:** You can use this repo to calculate similarity between given images. https://github.com/quickgrid/image-similarity**

If frames with certain objects(e.g., vehicle, device) are important, then use `pretrained object detectors` if available, to extract important frames.

Next, use a `similarity method` to remove similar images in nearby frames. Until a chosen `threshold` is exceeded keep removing nearby `N` frames.

This link should be helpful in finding right method for your case,

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48642/how-to-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images

This repository below should help implement the idea with few lines of code. It uses CNN to extract features then calculates there cosine distance as mentioned there.

https://github.com/ryanfwy/image-similarity